# 'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined for type 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a google sign in to my flutter application, but the method googleSignIn says:
'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined  for type 'FirebaseAuth'.
Here is my code

```
Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignIn() async{
      preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      setState(() {
      loading = true;
          });
      GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleUser.authentication;
      FirebaseUser  firebaseUser = await firebaseAuth.signInWithGoogle(
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken
      );


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth-class.html) that seems correct. The FirebaseAuth`class doesn't have a`signInWithGoogle`.

Are you looking for [`signInWithCredential`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithCredential.html) by any chance?

The [example](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/example/lib/signin_page.dart#L413) in the FlutterFire repo shows how to use this for Google sign in:

> ```
>   void _signInWithGoogle() async {
>     final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
>     final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
>         await googleUser.authentication;
>     final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
>       accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
>       idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
>     );
>     final FirebaseUser user =
>         (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
>     assert(user.email != null);
>     assert(user.displayName != null);
>     assert(!user.isAnonymous);
>     assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);
>
>    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
>     assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
>     setState(() {
>       if (user != null) {
>         _success = true;
>         _userID = user.uid;
>       } else {
>         _success = false;
>       }
>     });
>   }
> }
> ```